# how to plot the real-time predicted emotions for face emotion recognition

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I am doing a real-time face emotion recognition task, the code is as shown below. The emotion recognition part is doing fine. The thing I want to do further is to draw a real-time plot using the emotions predicted in real-time. Preferably, I want a frequency plot, for example, when the model predicts happy adds one to the happy column of the plot and I want the plot to update itself every time it predicts a new label/class/emotion.

I am pasting my code so you can clearly see what I am doing.

```py
%matplotlib notebook
from keras.models import load_model
from time import sleep
from keras_preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.preprocessing import image
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from random import randrange
from threading import Thread
import time


face_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
classifier =load_model(r'FinalModel64.h5')

emotion_labels = ['Angry','Fear','Happy','Neutral', 'Sad', 'Surprise']

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    labels = []
    emotion = []
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(gray)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,255),2)
        roi_color = frame[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        roi_color = cv2.resize(roi_color,(48,48),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

        if np.sum([roi_color])!=0:
            roi = roi_color.astype('float')/255.0
            roi = img_to_array(roi)
            roi = np.expand_dims(roi,axis=0)

            prediction = classifier.predict(roi)[0]
            labels = emotion_labels[prediction.argmax()]
            emotion = np.append(emotion, labels)
            label_position = (x,y)
            cv2.putText(frame,labels,label_position,cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),2)
        else:
            cv2.putText(frame,'No Faces',(30,80),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),2)
            
    cv2.imshow('Emotion Detector',frame)
    print(emotion)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hi, I'm just curious... I've seen several posts recently with a single quote `\`` before and after the code fence `\`\`\``. Is that something you've done intentionally, or is that being inserted by the editor? I'm trying to figure out if there's something that needs to be fixed on the Stack Overflow side.

Comment: No it was not on purpose I just used the Ctrl+K shortcut to insert the code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I searched on meta and found that this is a known problem. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421118/code-blocks-surrounded-by-single-backtick-then-triple-backticks.